# Error Traceback in Jinja2 when Extending Template

Tags: python, templates, jinja2, extends

I’m using template inheritance in jinja2 because I have a top bar in my website that I need to include in all pages. The problem is that whenever there is an error in any page the traceback always points to the line with the `{% extends %}` tag and I cannot locate the source of the error.

Is there a way to find out which line is causing the error (aside from reading the whole code myself) or another way to do template inheritance than `{% extends %}`?

Comment: post the error traceback here...

Comment: File "D:\BitBucket\Code\purchasing\templates\catalogue.html", line 1, in top-level template code
    {% extends 'purchasing/templates/navbar.html' %}
UndefinedError: 'fg' is undefined

Comment: As you see in the traceback message you are using an undefined variable in the `cataloge.html` template called `fg`. Check this variable or include the relevant templates in your question as well.

Comment: Well duh. My problem is that the error message doesn't specify which line not that I am facing an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after trying a lot of things, I found that the best way to do this is to use iframes instead of the Jinja `extend`. This way, not only can I locate the source of the error, I don’t have to send the Python values I am using in the frames to each template that I am going to render. I only send them to the original class that creates the iframe template.

Answer (score 1):

Although iframes are more accustomed to importing webpages from different websites, this might be a good idea. You could also use the jinja tag `{% include %}` and then use sessions to cache the data instead of reloading them in every page.